# Find any part of a text string of keywords separated by spaces

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to match any part of a text string of keywords to text in the Target cell.

If it is a text value, of a single keyword, like "wal" for Wal-mart, then this code finds the text string in the Target, i.e. " WAL-MART SUPERCENTER ".

When I have "wal otherstore" in the keywords cell it doesn't find Wal-mart anymore. I thought that is what xlPart was supposed to do.

```vb
Set Found = Target.Find(What:=Cell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
```

The idea is to have a list of accounts in a budget spreadsheet with associated keywords, so that the macro then finds keywords, like "wal" and assigns the Target entry to that account.
The keywords are all in a single cell next to the accounts list. The keywords are separated by a space.

Full code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Rng3 As Range, Cell As Range, Found As Range
Dim List As String
Dim Qty As Integer
Dim Coll As Collection
Dim i As Long

LastRowA = Sheets("Transactions").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastRowL = Sheets("Transactions").Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
List = "Reset Options"
Qty = 0

Set Coll = New Collection
Set Rng1 = Sheets("Transactions").Range("G3:G" & LastRowA)
Set Rng2 = Sheets("Accounts & Budget").Range("I5:I104")
Set Rng3 = Sheets("Transactions").Range("L3:L" & LastRowL)

If Application.Intersect(Target, Rng1) Is Nothing Then
ElseIf Application.Intersect(Target, Rng1).Address = Target.Address Then
    If Target = "" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Offset(0, 5).Validation.Delete
        Cells(Target.Row, "G") = ""
        Cells(Target.Row, "L") = ""
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    ElseIf Target <> "" Then
        For Each Cell In Rng2
            Set Found = Target.Find(What:=Cell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
            If Found Is Nothing Then
            Else
                Qty = Qty + 1
                Coll.Add Cell.Offset(0, -2)
            End If
        Next Cell
        If Qty = 1 And Coll.Count = 1 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Offset(0, 5).Validation.Delete
            Target.Offset(0, 5) = Coll(1)
            Target.Offset(0, 5).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Accounts"
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        ElseIf Qty = 0 And Coll.Count = 0 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Offset(0, 5).Validation.Delete
            Target.Offset(0, 5) = "No Results - Select From List"
            Target.Offset(0, 5).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Accounts"
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        ElseIf Qty > 1 And Coll.Count > 1 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Offset(0, 5).Validation.Delete
            Target.Offset(0, 5) = "Multiple Results - Select From List"
            For i = 1 To Coll.Count
                List = List & "," & Coll(i)
            Next i
            Target.Offset(0, 5).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=List
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End If

If Application.Intersect(Target, Rng3) Is Nothing Then
ElseIf Application.Intersect(Target, Rng3).Address = Target.Address Then
    If Target = "Reset Options" Or Target = "" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Validation.Delete
        Target.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Accounts"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Target = "Select From List"
    ElseIf Target.Offset(0, -5) = "" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Validation.Delete
        Target = ""
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand `xlPart` - it means that only a part of the cell content has to match the search word, e.g. 'Wal mart', 'two walls', 'Walter', 'Wal' will be returned if you search for 'Wal' with xlPart set. Whereas `xlWhole` will only return a cell with content 'Wal'

Comment: Start to try to find your error by removing the `On Error Resume Next` line.

Comment: Hello Ike - your explanation of xlPart is how I understand it, and exactly what I needed. I'll work on the code again today, as Ron suggested - I added the ```On Error Resume Next``` because of a repeating error. Which I believed was because not all the accounts have keywords right now, so the Cell reference is empty.

Comment: By ***cell reference*** do you mean **`Found**`? If so, you should be testing just for that with a statement like `If not Found is Nothing then ...`.  If that doesn't work, then the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I tried the suggestions, but no luck. It got me thinking ... Using Excel's Ctrl + F find function on the same range is technically the same right? Searching for a single text string, yields results, but using two text strings doesn't. I think the same thing happens in the code. The target text string is for example "test store wal-mart date text" and using the keyword "wal" works just fine. But if the cell containing the keywords contains "wal storeA StoreB" then nothing is found. Which makes sense to an extent. Or should the partial text match work on the target AND the keyword string?

Comment: I've posted the full Sub - just in case there is a better way to find a partial match in the target string and a keyword string with multiple keywords. The keywords are in ```Rng2 = Sheets("Accounts & Budget").Range("I5:I104")``` and separated by a space